# Non Deterministc Dimensionality reduction

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cross-validation, dimensionality-reduction

could you please suggest me a nondeterministic algorithm for dimensionality reduction except t-SNE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Autoencoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) are non-deterministic, since they rely on a random weight initialization.